# No module named _version_helper

Tags: python

Am trying to install django-cities-light==2.4.2. But am getting error "No module named _version_helper".

```
pip install django-cities-light==2.4.2
```

error:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-autoslug (from django-cities
light==2.4.2)
Downloading django-autoslug-1.9.0.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:/home/ranjeet/virtualenv/booking_api/build/django-autoslug/setup.py) egg_info for package django-autoslug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/home/ranjeet/virtualenv/booking_api/build/django-autoslug/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _version_helper import __version__
ImportError: No module named _version_helper
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 17, in

File "/home/ranjeet/virtualenv/booking_api/build/django-autoslug/setup.py", line 18, in

```
from _version_helper import __version__
```

ImportError: No module named _version_helper

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/ranjeet/virtualenv/booking_api/build/django-autoslug
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ranjeet/.pip/pip.log

Comment: They have [a mailing list](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light#resources).

Comment: I'm having the same issue without django-cities-light.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was related to version of django-cities-light==2.4.2 dependencies.

```
'six',
'unidecode>=0.04.13',
'django_autoslug',
```

this error occur with django_autoslug version. Because current version of django_autoslug is "django-autoslug 1.9.0".

for `django-cities-light==2.4.2` django_autoslug should be `django-autoslug 1.6.1`.